# To get provider from ManagementObjectSearcher Win32_PnPEntity

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port, usb, win32com

I am searching for my USB to Serial converter. I have two objectives:

1. To get the USB Port Number
2. To get the Provider

Here under is the screenshot from my **Device Manager**

[image]

Now my motto is to recognize this USB to Serial Bridge which is provided by `ATEN`, However I am not specifically looking for the ATEN thing, just I need to know how to query `ManagementObject`

*Because if I look for `Caption` for some systems it is `ATEN USB to Serial Bridge` and for some systems it is `USB-to-Serial Comm. Port`, and maybe for some other it will become something else. What never changes is the `Provider - "ATEN"`*

Following is my code:

`Now I have did something here under to get/extract data from **CAPTION**`

```
using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE Caption like '%ATEN USB to Serial Bridge%'"))
{
    foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
    {
        foreach (PropertyData prop in queryObj.Properties)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("{0}: {1}", prop.Name, prop.Value));
        }

        string s = queryObj["Caption"].ToString();

        // Here under i play with the string `s` to get the `CCOM21`
        int start = s.IndexOf("(");
        int end = s.IndexOf(")");
        result = s.Substring(start, end - start);
        result = result.Replace("(", "");

        list.Items.Add(result);
    }
}
```

I know its not the right way to do but how I can get the `COM21` port and `Provider - ATEN` by query **ManagementObject**. Or is there any other direct way to do this.